# Contextual menu not displayed in 10.5 for application build in 10.7

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have created an application in 10.7, where i used contextual menu for tableview. When right click event occurs, contextual menu is displayed. This works fine.

But, when the same executable is run in 10.5, and right clicked on table view contextual menu is not displayed at all.

It seems menuNeedsUpdate: method is not called at all.

Can any one suggests for this issue?

Regards,
iSIght

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Leopard you have to subclass NSTableView, implement `menuForEvent:` and fetch and return the menu from your table's delegate or datasource.

Alternatively you could try hooking up the table's `menu` outlet in Interface Builder.